# Schengen Visa D and C. Do I need the second one if I aready have the first one?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, italy

I have a Schengen visa (Polish) type D that expires on April 30, 2024 (multiple). On May 2024 I have to go to Italy to participate in a sports event. Do I need to get a type-C visa for this or I can go there with my type-D visa? If I get a type C while the type D is valid, will the type D no longer be available after my type C expires (it will be given for one month or so)?

Comment: Are you living in Poland?  If not, why do you have a valid D visa?  If the reason for issuing it no longer applies, it might have been invalidated.  On the other hand, if you have a valid Polish residence permit, you do not need a visa.

Comment: You can’t use your D visa to travel unless it’s valid. Since it expires *before* your intended trip to Italy, it won’t be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to open type C visa for this or I can go there with type D visa?

You will need a short-stay (C) visa since your D visa (and your permission to stay in the Schengen Area) would expire before you want to go to Italy.

> If I get a type C while the type D is valid, will the type D no longer be available after my type C expires (it will be given for one month or so)?

Getting a C visa will not affect your D visa in any way, shape or form